# css3 center div

Tags: css

How can I center a `div` using the flexible box model of CSS3? The div should not have a fixed size. I'm looking for a simple example that does only that (most examples I found do a lot more and I haven't yet reduced them to something simple).

For example, center the following box horizontally on the page:

```
<div class='centered'>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p><img src='sample.png'/></p>
</div>
```

Comment: center horizontally? vertically? what should it contain? please provide an example on jsfiddle or jsbin

Answer (score 1):

[Dead center](http://www.wpdfd.com/editorial/thebox/deadcentre4.html).

You need to set a horizon with visible overflow and play from there.

Comment: This is using a fixed width for the `content` block though.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y You can avoid setting a fixed `width`, but you still need to set at least a fixed `height` - see my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lorenzopolidori/Nrsss/56/). This is because you can't place the content block with the horizon passing through the middle without knowing the actual height of the block.